# GNAT GPS plug-in: Action object has no attribute button

Tags: python, gnat-gps

I'm writing

```
GPS.Action("Copy to Clipboard").button(toolbar='Messages', label='Copy')
```

which is exactly how it is documented here: http://docs.adacore.com/gps-docs/users_guide/_build/html/GPS.html#GPS.Action.create

but I'm getting the error: `'Action' object has no attribute 'button'`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Which GNAT GPS version are you using? Previous versions (2013, for example) does not have this method.